# Get local path from network path

Tags: windows, operations

I have a funny situation. I am sitting on a computer on which there is a shared folder, say, "My_Folder". So, I can access it using the address "\My_Box\My_Folder".

Now, if I write a small tool in C#, I can convert the "\My_Box\My_Folder" to "C:\My_Folder" which is its physically location.

The funny thing is that I don't know how to find the physically location of "My_Box\My_Folder" without my program ... And it's actually one of my friend's problem.

So if anyone knows how to find the local path from a network path with some simple basic Windows commands/operations (either Winxp, 2000, vista, 7, ...), please let me know.

Thanks,
Pete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is a command line tool that will provide this information then you can simply use the `net share` command that’s built into Windows.

If you need to do it programmatically you can use the `NetShareGetInfo` function. The following example shows how to use it to query the path for `\\localhost\share` in C++.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <lm.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "netapi32.lib")

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    BYTE * buffer = nullptr;

    auto error = NetShareGetInfo(nullptr, // local computer
                                 L"share",
                                 2, // level
                                 &buffer);

    if (ERROR_SUCCESS == error)
    {
        auto info = reinterpret_cast<SHARE_INFO_2 *>(buffer);

        wcout << info->shi2_path << endl;
    }

    if (buffer)
    {
        NetApiBufferFree(buffer);
    }
}
```

I would wrap the buffer in a class and call `NetApiBufferFree` from its destructor but that’s up to you.